# Callback function in .Move() of scriptaculous

Tags: javascript, callback, effect, scriptaculous

I am trying to something like this.

```
new Effect.Move('moveee', { x: -150}, { afterFinish: function () { console.log(x); } });
```

But it is not working. Where is the wrong ??

Comment: Did you try `new Effect.Move('moveee', { x: -150, afterFinish: function () { console.log(x); } });`

Comment: Thanks @Quantastical for your reply and it is working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Effect.Move` function accepts two parameters. You are passing in three. You need to move the `afterFinish` property and value to the second parameter, like so:

```
new Effect.Move(
  'moveee', 
  {
    x: -150,
    afterFinish: function ()
    {
      console.log(x);
    }
  }
);
```